# Pandas replaces NAN with arbitrary number when to_latex

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a large multi-indexed multi-columned dataframe `df`, that I'm not showing here. I generate a slice of index like this:

```
subDf = df.sort_index(level=0).loc[:'e']
```

This slice then contains `NaN` in the second level of the index:

```
>>> subDf.iloc[0:1]
                  change
robustness value        
baseline   NaN     -14.5
```

The csv generated by `to_csv()` appears to be correct:

```
>>> subDf.iloc[0:1].to_csv()
Out[15]: 'robustness,value,change\nbaseline,,-14.5\n'
```

Similarly, `to_html()` is functioning like expeted. However, when I try to get the latex_output, the `NaN` vanishes and a `50.00` appears:

```
>>> subDf.iloc[0:1].to_latex()
Out[14]: u'\\begin{tabular}{llr}\n\\toprule\n                &       &  change \\\\\nrobustness & value &         \\\\\n\\midrule\nbaseline & 50.00 &   -14.5 \\\\\n\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n'
```

The `50.00` is not a completely arbitrary number, it is the last value in the second-layer of the multi-index in the original data frame:

```
>>> df.index
Out[18]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'baseline', u'f'], [0.01, 0.04, 0.25, 0.75, 0.86, 0.99, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 10.0, 50.0]],
           labels=[[5, 6, 6, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 9, 10]],
           names=[u'robustness', u'value'])
```

Two questions arise:

- why is this happening in the first place?
- if it is indeed unexpected behavior that I can't affect in the short run, how can I circumvent this and force `to_latex()` to print out a `NaN`?

Comment: This smells like a bug, does `to_html()` behave correctly?

Comment: @EdChum Yes it does.

Comment: I suggest posting an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) you may also get a quick response on the [gitter](https://gitter.im/pydata/pandas) channel

Comment: For latecomers, the issue is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14249) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably much too late to help, but for posterity, but I think either of these approaches should work:

1. Convert the column with the `NaN`s to string; this will give you `nan` in the LaTeX.
2. If you'd rather have `NaN` than `nan`, you can either do 1. and then replace or you can just do `df.fillna('NaN')`.

Obviously these approaches modify your dataframe in a way that isn't good for further analysis, but I think this is an easy workaround; just make a copy of your dataframe first.

(I tested these approaches on a dataframe with just a single-level index, but I can't imagine that it would work any differently for multi-level)